Azure DevOps Pipeline Throwing Error while trying to deploy a VM to Azure
I am trying to deploy a VM in an existing availability set and VNET/SNET in a particular existing Resource Group I am using open source Terraform and my state file is stored in a storage container
This is my pipeline file below
variables:
  - group: infra-variables
  
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - Terraform-Test 
    exclude:
    - README.md
  
stages:
- stage: Validate
  displayName: Validate
  jobs:
  - job: validate
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - checkout : self 
    # - task: AzureCLI@2
    #   displayName : 
    #   inputs:
    #     azureSubscription: 'PalTest'
    #     scriptType: 'bash'
    #     scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    #     inlineScript: |
    #       az account set --subscription $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    #       az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $AZURE_TENANT_ID 
    #       STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=$(az storage account keys list -g $(Terraform_Backend_RG) -n $(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME) | jq ".[0].value" -r)
    #       echo "setting storage account key variable"
    #       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_ACCESS_KEY;issecret=true]$ARM_ACCESS_KEY"

    - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
      displayName: Install Terraform
      inputs:
        terraformVersion: 'latest'


  # Init
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Terraform Init
      inputs:
        backendType : 'azurerm'
        command: 'init'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
        backendServiceArm: 'Pallab-ADO-Setup'
        backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(Terraform_Backend_RG)
        backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME)
        backendAzureRmContainerName: $(TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
        backendAzureRmKey: 'infrastructure/terraform.ntfstate'
        

  # Validate
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Validate Config
      inputs:
        command: 'validate'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'

- stage: Plan
  displayName: Plan
  jobs:
  - job: plan
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
      displayName: Install Terraform
      inputs:
        terraformVersion: 'latest'

  # Init
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Terraform Init
      inputs:
        backendType : 'azurerm'
        command: 'init'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
        backendServiceArm: 'Pallab-ADO-Setup'
        backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(Terraform_Backend_RG)
        backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME)
        backendAzureRmContainerName: $(TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
        backendAzureRmKey: 'infrastructure/terraform.ntfstate'

  # Plan
    - task: TerraformCLI@0
      displayName: Plan Terraform Deployment
      inputs:
        backendType : 'azurerm'
        command: 'plan'
        commandOptions: '-input=false'
        environmentServiceName : 'Pallab-ADO-Setup'
        workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
        # backendServiceArm: 'PalTest'
        # backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: $(Terraform_Backend_RG)
        # backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: $(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME)
        # backendAzureRmContainerName: $(TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
        # backendAzureRmKey: 'infrastructure/terraform.tfstate'

# Approve
- stage: Approve
  displayName: Approve
  jobs:
  - job: approve
    displayName: Wait for approval
    pool: server
    steps: 
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 60
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: 'pallabcd@hotmail.com'
        instructions: 'Review the plan in the next hour'

- stage: Apply
  displayName: Apply
  jobs:
  - job: apply
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: Install Terraform
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: 'latest'
      
      # Init
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: TF Init 
        env:
          ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)
        inputs:
          command: 'init'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
          commandOptions: '-backend-config=storage_account_name=$(TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME) -backend-config=container_name=$(TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME) -backend-config=key=$(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)'
          backendType: 'selfConfigured'


      # Apply
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: TF Apply 
        env:
          ARM_SAS_TOKEN: $(ARM_ACCESS_KEY)
          ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(AZURE_CLIENT_ID)
          ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET)
          ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
          ARM_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
        inputs:
          command: 'apply'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Terraform-Test'
          commandOptions: '-auto-approve'

The Plan Stage shows three resources are getting created successfully "Terraform Init" under Plan stage shows the below out put :
/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.9.5/x64/terraform init -backend-config=storage_account_name=glcontoso -backend-config=container_name=markdev -backend-config=key=infrastructure/terraform.ntfstate -backend-config=resource_group_name=CKA-Rg -backend-config=subscription_id=*** -backend-config=tenant_id=*** -backend-config=client_id=*** -backend-config=client_secret=***
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 2.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/azuread versions matching "~> 2.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.99.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v2.99.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/azuread v2.53.1...
- Installed hashicorp/azuread v2.53.1 (signed by HashiCorp)
Terraform has created a lock file .terraform.lock.hcl to record the provider
selections it made above. Include this file in your version control repository
so that Terraform can guarantee to make the same selections by default when
you run "terraform init" in the future.

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

But TF init is failing in the apply stage The error that it throws is given below
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]executed command 'init'
##[debug]set TERRAFORM_LAST_EXITCODE=1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=TERRAFORM_LAST_EXITCODE;isOutput=false;issecret=false;]1
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The specified resource does not exist.\nRequestId:548f5df2-901e-005b-5bb8-fcf38a000000\nTime:2024-09-01T21:45:01.8826214Z"
│ 
│ 
╵

##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The specified resource does not exist.\nRequestId:548f5df2-901e-005b-5bb8-fcf38a000000\nTime:2024-09-01T21:45:01.8826214Z"
│ 
│ 

I then changed the Access Level in the Storage Account to :
"Container(anonymous read access for containers and blobs)
Now i am getting the below error :
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]backendType=selfConfigured
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]command=init
##[debug]executed command 'init'
##[debug]set TERRAFORM_LAST_EXITCODE=1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=TERRAFORM_LAST_EXITCODE;isOutput=false;issecret=false;]1
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]╷
│ Error: Error loading state: failed to lock azure state: blobs.Client#PutBlockBlob: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The specified resource does not exist.\nRequestId:0c2f1a76-601e-003d-0ebf-fcbcaa000000\nTime:2024-09-01T22:40:47.8315889Z"
│ blobs.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF
│ 
│ 
╵

##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]╷
│ Error: Error loading state: failed to lock azure state: blobs.Client#PutBlockBlob: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The specified resource does not exist.\nRequestId:0c2f1a76-601e-003d-0ebf-fcbcaa000000\nTime:2024-09-01T22:40:47.8315889Z"
│ blobs.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF
│ 
│ 
╵

##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]╷
│ Error: Error loading state: failed to lock azure state: blobs.Client#PutBlockBlob: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The specified resource does not exist.\nRequestId:0c2f1a76-601e-003d-0ebf-fcbcaa000000\nTime:2024-09-01T22:40:47.8315889Z"
│ blobs.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"" '\x00' '\x00'} error: EOF
│ 


Can you also share your Terraform code, please?

Why are you running terraform init more than once?

Also, it is now generally considered bad practice to use Terraform workspaces, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QgHLncP5VA and https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/workspaces#when-not-to-use-multiple-workspaces
